# How to change scalar variable in Workspace from Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have created Body in Simulink/SimMechanics where CS1 is located [0, length, 0] from CG. Before the simulation starts I set variable `length = 1` but I need change it during simulation to `length = 0.8`. Yes, I really want to change size of the object on the fly.
I'm changing it because of some event in StateFlow.
I tried write this new `length` to Workspace by Simulink block `To Workspace`, but it can't save scalar variable.

Does anybody know how to save scalar variable from Simulink to Matlab Workspace?

Comment: Can you set To Workspace to save only the last sample?

Comment: There are unfortunately only options: `Timeseries`, `Structure`, `Structure with time` and `Array`. I can't see any other option. Regularly you want all history of some data measurement not only the last value. My want is quite unusual.

Comment: I don't believe you can change that parameter on the fly. The only thing I can suggest is changing the value of `length` and then using `set_param` to assign this new value to the block, but even that I doubt will work. BTW, you shouldn't name your variable `length`, it's the name of a built-in function in MATLAB.

Comment: It all was probably wrong way. It is probably not possible. Thank you for attention about variable name `length`, but I didn't used it - that was only example.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you just need to save some scalar in Matlab from Simulink. I just got the same problem and can give you an example:

[image: Look at this]
So I use variable MySeed from Matlab. All secret that I use `Timeseries` option in `ToWorkspace` block, but `Inherit: auto` for `FromWorkspace`. This means I can define MySeed in Matlab like an `Array` of this type: `[0 78]`. The first column is used for timing in Simulink so I don't use it. But second is just a data and you can use it like a scalar value. Simulink load it and use SECOND column (my data).
The problem that I have time simulation = 6000. So in this case I'll get so big array I really don't use. so you can use `Decimation` option in `ToWorkspace` block! I set it at 6000 and now it create timeseries in Workspace with 2 elements only - for t = 0 and t = 6000. I make BOTH of them with my values so I can use any of it in my program.
I hope this can help you!